# csv file input, algorithm calculating distance

Tags: python, algorithm, csv, input, python-3.6

Hello i am struggling with algorithm that will calculate distance made by operator in warehouse. It is calculated based on picklist that contains set of locations. i just set distances between them. I have created "mini" algorithm version with hand input for few locations, but im aiming for picklists with over 100k locations. I would like to input variables "picklist" and "LOCA" - """locations""" from csv file. i have managed to do it by this code:

```
with open("movement warehouse.csv") as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    next(csv_reader)
    for row in csv_reader:
        picklist, number, LOCA, ITEM, DATE = row
        print(row)
```

it prints this:

```
['4403821', '10', 'E-11-GR', 'NSWH-828031C', '20-Jun-17']

['4403824', '10', 'I-15-BL', 'CISH-800-100174-01', '20-Jun-17']

['4403825', '10', 'I-02-ER', 'CISH-800-100175-01', '20-Jun-17']

['4403825', '20', 'G-21-FR', 'CISH-700-101709-01', '20-Jun-17']
```

(its just part of it, but u get the idea)

so the first column is number of picklist and the third one is location.
Others dont matter for me for now. 
So finally my question:
How can I use particular "cell" of data for example: I'd like to check:

```
if first picklist = second picklist:   #thats possible
   distance += (distance between location'E-11-GR'and 'I-15-BL'
else:
   skip to next location #or whatever
```

You get the idea? how to go through data by rows in column ( from csv file )

PS.:
Im beginner, working in python for 3 weeks now and this is my first post here, so go easy on me please :) and if this post is to messy let me know ill try to explain better

Comment: [Edit] your Question and show how you calculate `distance`, by `index` or?

Answer (score 1):

You want to access the array indexes.

Every row you get will come in as an array:

```
my_row = ["1", "foo", "bar"]
```

you can get the first by saying:

```
my_row[0]
```

Arrays begin at zero, so `bar` would be at `my_row[2]`.

If you ask for a term that's not in the array (`my_row[5]`) it'll throw an error, so make sure the data is there before you ask for it.

The structure of your code might look something like this:

```
all_rows = []
for row in csv_reader:
    all_rows.append(row)

'To get the first row:
all_rows[0]
'To get the first column of the first row:
all_rows[0][0]
```

Comment: i know but when i have 10000 rows and eg. print(my_row[0]) it will print 10000 values from first column and i want to be able to specify "print(A12)" sort of like in excel

Comment: See my edit- I think you need to store the list somewhere in memory before you're going to be able to do that. Also, the way you're reading it right now, you're right, you'll end up with columns then rows, which is bad because then you have no way of accessing them.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's an elegant way of solving this with dictionaries.

Assuming that picklist is our reference point(?)

```
master_dict = defaultdict(list) #sets up a dictionary with a list as the default value
for row in csv:
    value = dict(zip(['number', 'LOCA', 'ITEM', 'DATE'], row[1:]))
    master_dict[row[0]].append(value)
```

Then you can iterate through the keys?